# Lookup in Excel between tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

The image below shows three parts of my table.

The yellow cell is the cell I am trying to pull information into (cell F18) which is in the Know Your Business table.

The red cell is my drop down by month (Cell U16).

The bottom table is some financial data for each month. To make it easier to help with the formula, I have named the cells for the row that is relevant.

The financial data at the bottom I want to pull through to the Know Your Business table. So when I change the month in U16, the data in the Know Your Business table is the data for that month.

If someone can help me figure out the first box (cell F18), I can replicate it to do all boxes in the Know Your Business table with the relevant rows.

So in the image, if working correctly:

If the month dropdown said `Apr`, the cell F18 would say Aprils figure of £8,667.  If I then changed it to `Jan`, it would change to £8,000.

[image: IMAGE OF SPREADSHEET]
*<sub>Right-Click image for larger view in another tab.</sub>*

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Maybe **H**LOOKUP?

Comment: Thank you - sorry I am fairly basic in use so am not sure how to do that. I have been told I can do it by INDEX and MATCH but the formula didn't work

Comment: @Akina - you're right `HLOOKUP`. @ Chris - Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1466217/edit) to let us know what the `INDEX/MATCH` formula you tried is?

Comment: I have added it in to the detail in my question - thank you

Comment: I added an image for people to see - thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula that you're looking for is

```
=HLOOKUP(U16,E117:T117,5,FALSE)
```

Enter the formula above in cell "F18"

Comment: Thank you that is great